# Servidor local não atualiza o css e javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Toda vez que eu entro no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento eu tenho que limpar o cache do navegador para o css e o javascript do arquivo funcionar ou colocar "?1" na frente do arquivo que puxa o css e o js para forçar o servidor a atualizar. Já coloquei `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />`, mas não funciona. Se eu desligar o pc e ligar novamente eu tenho que forçar novamente o servidor a atualizar, mas isso tem acontecido atualmente. Alguém sabe porque isso pode estar acontecendo? Eu tenho um projeto grande com muitas páginas php, muitos arquivos css e js, isso pode influenciar?

Comment: Qual SO você utiliza e qual o programa você utiliza pra gerenciar seu servidor (WAMP, MAMP, XAMPP)? Pode ser alguma configuração de cache do PHP.

Comment: Utilizo o Linux e Lamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. O navegador fica armazenando cache e travando. Nesse link aqui tem algumas coisas interessantes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development